# Is there a difference between these tensorflow commands?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, image-classification

I'm trying to finetune Resnet50; do these two methods produce the same results?

```
base_model = ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
model = models.Sequential()    
model.add(base_model)
model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7, 7))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(5, activation=softmax))
```

and

```
base_model = ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
headModel = base_model.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7, 7))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(5, activation="softmax")(headModel)
model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)
```

Comment: In this case, they will output the same. The first is the `Sequential API`. The second is the `Functional API`. Sequential, like the name suggests, is a sequence of layers in a simple, directed path. Functional provides more control over your model, allowing more complex models than a single sequence of layers. Also the Functional model outputs layers. Sequential outputs tensors.

Comment: @Djinn Thanks, I see what you're saying and I think I need to look into the difference between the two a little more.